# Proof of Convergence $+$ Identifying Probability Distribution

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove the convergence of the series below to 1 and it seemed to be strikingly similar to a probability distribution I once saw. My question is twofold:

$1$. Can anyone identify the distribution? I can't seem to find it on google and it's really killing me because I'm 90% sure this is a probability distribution (or some form of one).
 $2$. Do you have any hints for proving this convergence? I don't necessarily want an answer, just some pointers.

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-j}j^{j-1}}{j!}}= 1
$$

Please let me know if this is a duplicate question. Thank you!

Comment: Empirically (2) seems to be  true, with the sum of the first $n$ terms being about $1- \dfrac{0.79788\ldots}{\sqrt{n}}$ for large $n$

Comment: And $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\approx 0.7978846$

Comment: @Henry You are right, I finally managed to get an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

For those curious, I have written an answer here for completeness. Thanks to considerable help, here is the solution for convergence:

Let $f(x) = xe^{-x}$. We use the taylor expansion of $f^{-1}(x) = -W(-xe^{-x})$ via taylor expansion of the Lambert W function given by:

$$
W(y) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-j)^{j-1}y^j}{j!}
$$

so

$$
-W(-xe^{-x}) =  \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{j^{j-1}(xe^{-x})^j}{j!} = x
$$

Setting $x = 1$, we get the desired convergence:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-j}j^{j-1}}{j!} = 1
$$